# Manage many cookie with the same session_id

Tags: php, cookies

I am using PHP to create a cookie. My question is that when I am opening two web page with the same `session_id` the cookie value of one page will override the value of the other, which can create a problem if each cookie contains data of different users.

So how can I prevent this?

Comment: Have you tried to check if the cookie already exists?

Comment: cookies are stored on client side, everytime client send request, cookies are included and server load cookies from request everytime, sessions are stored on server side, each session file has identificator coresponding with phpsessid (which is cookie) and server manage this ids to never be same for multiple clients, so if you mean session_id as phpsessid then don't worry this never happen in real scenario. insead of cookies use sessions - they are not setable in client

Comment: Try to check if cookie exists and use if statement to set new cookie or update existing one according to your need